# FB posting failure

Tags: android, ios, facebook, authentication, unity-game-engine

In one of the devices, some user postings fail in both Android and iOS after the FB connection has been established. FB button for posting does not work in these cases, so the posting is done through AddBinaryData("image") for /me/photos/ with FB.API.

There is an error associated with the result callback. We checked the error message and the only thing we found was: `400:Bad Request`. Can anyone please help us solve this issue?

---

Unity Version ： 4.6.5

Facebook SDK Version ： 6.0

Facebook Build Version ： 140805.da738911cf62c00

iOS Version ： 8.1.3

note:
We changed the following source to work it in 4.6.5.
Place: Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs’s row 411,

if UNITY_4_5
This symbol is assigned in Unity Version 4.5.x, however its changed in
Unity 4.6.x to the following:

UNITY_4_6
Therefore, places at FB.cs will not judge correctly and as a result it will not move correctly in 4.6.x. So we had to change 4.6.x, so that will work on ver4.6

if UNITY_4_6.

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to help without your code.

Comment: I am sorry. Here it is...I appreciate any help! Thanks!                                           WWWForm _form = new WWWForm();
  form.AddBinaryData("image", byte);
  FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, (_result)=>{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_result.Error)) {
   　　// success
   }
   else {
    // failure
   }
  }, _form);

Comment: 1) If you are able to repro this, then I would advice you trying this without unity first (e.g. with curl) and see if you get the same results. 2) try updating the SDK and see if that helps. 3) try the sample project InteractiveConsole and see if you can repro there as well, if not, this might be an issue in your code somewhere else.